# SwiftUI navigation bar title and items does not disappear when swiping back fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, swiftui

[image]

The problem is that the title and the item of the navigation bar does not disappear which is an unexpected behaviour.

```
struct DestinationView: View {

@State private var showingActionSheet = false

var body: some View {
    Text("DestinationView")
        .padding(.top, 100)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Destination"), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            print("tapped")
        }, label: {
            Text("second")
        }))
        .actionSheet(isPresented: self.$showingActionSheet) { () -> ActionSheet in
            ActionSheet(title: Text("Settings"), message: nil, buttons: [
                .default(Text("Delete"), action: {
                }),
                .cancel()
            ])
        }

}

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It's really annoying. Do you fixed it?

Comment: I just figured out that issue only exists if you have BarButtonItems on the detail page

Comment: Any good Solution for this one so far? I ran into the exact same issue. But for me it just appears if i dismiss the View programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the .navigationBarTitle(), .navigationBarItems() modifiers and the .actionSheet() modifier are under each other in code. (But it can be the .alert() or the .overlay() modifiers as well instead of .actionSheet())

The solution in this case:

```
struct DestinationView: View {

@State private var showingActionSheet = false

var body: some View {

    List {
        Text("DestinationView")
            .padding(.top, 100)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Destination"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                print("tapped")
            }, label: {
                Text("second")
            }))
    }
    .actionSheet(isPresented: self.$showingActionSheet) { () -> ActionSheet in
        ActionSheet(title: Text("Settings"), message: nil, buttons: [
            .default(Text("Delete"), action: {
            }),
            .cancel()
        ])
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is it a documented behavior that action sheet can't be used together with navigation bar customizations? I personally feel it's a bug in SwiftUI and filed a bug report.

Just FYI: Another possible workaround could be to wrap the `actionSheet` in a conditional where the condition is the same as the one used for `isPresented`.

Comment: I also think it is a bug, I haven't found any documentation on that. The suggested workaround is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

to the NavigationView seems to fix it for me.

Comment: This does not work if you want to use it on iPad without the StackNavigationViewStyle.